# Subtracting two ranges in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Dear stackoverflow community, I found myself solutions for many problems in other programming languages, now I made myself and account here so I can ask specific question about things I struggle with. I'm making model in excel and tbh I'm pretty poor programmer looking to get better with VBA. My question is, how can I subtract two ranges and then write results in some other column. 
It would look like this:
[image: this]
I have two ranges (B2:B4) subtracting them with (*C2:C4*) and writing the results in (D2:D4). (D2=B2 - C2,D3=B3 - C3 etc.)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range ("D2:D4").FormulaR1C1="=RC[-2] - RC[-1]"

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("D2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
        Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(lastRow, 4)).Select
        Selection.FillDown
    End With
End Sub
```